# insert event in google calender using php

Tags: php, events, calendar, google-calendar-api

I am trying to add event in Google Calendar using PHP. Following is my code:

```
    $event = new Google_Event(); 
    $event->setSummary('Halloween'); 
    $event->setLocation('The Neighbourhood'); 
    $start = new Google_EventDateTime(); 
    $start->setDateTime('2018-1-19T10:00:00.000-05:00'); 
    $event->setStart($start); 
    $end = new Google_EventDateTime();
    $end->setDateTime('2018-1-19TT10:25:00.000-05:00'); 
    $event->setEnd($end); 
    $createdEvent = $cal->events->insert('primary', $event);
```

I am getting access to calendar but event is not getting added. Please help me. I am using [this library](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client).

Comment: @BlackMamba I have updated my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to follow the example in the official documentation: [Events: insert](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert#examples).

```
// Refer to the PHP quickstart on how to setup the environment: // https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/php // Change the scope to Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR and delete any stored // credentials.

$event = new Google_Service_Calendar_Event(array(   'summary' => 'Google I/O 2015',   'location' => '800 Howard St., San Francisco, CA 94103',   'description' => 'A chance to hear more about Google\'s developer products.',   'start' => array(
    'dateTime' => '2015-05-28T09:00:00-07:00',
    'timeZone' => 'America/Los_Angeles',   ),   'end' => array(
    'dateTime' => '2015-05-28T17:00:00-07:00',
    'timeZone' => 'America/Los_Angeles',   ),   'recurrence' => array(
    'RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=2'   ),   'attendees' => array(
    array('email' => 'lpage@example.com'),
    array('email' => 'sbrin@example.com'),   ),   'reminders' => array(
    'useDefault' => FALSE,
    'overrides' => array(
      array('method' => 'email', 'minutes' => 24 * 60),
      array('method' => 'popup', 'minutes' => 10),
    ),   ), ));

$calendarId = 'primary'; $event = $service->events->insert($calendarId, $event); printf('Event created: %s\n', $event->htmlLink);
```